# Compute a function on a 3-d meshgrid in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have data some data and I would like to compute the likelihood function given the data over a grid of the parameters in the model. My problem is when it comes to computing the function on the meshgrid I get ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together.

I have likelihood function

```
import numpy as np
def log_likelihood_function(A,nu_0,alpha,nu,x_i,sigma):
    nu=np.array(nu)
    x_i=np.array(x_i)
    
    return -len(nu)/2*np.log(2*np.pi*sigma**2)-1/(2*sigma**2)*np.sum((x_i-A*(nu/nu_0)**alpha*(1+nu/nu_0)**(-4*alpha))**2)
    
def model(A,nu_0,alpha,nu):
    
    return A*(nu/nu_0)**alpha*(1+nu/nu_0)**(-4*alpha)
```

A,nu_0 and alpha are parameters over which I would like to compute the likelihood, sigma is a constant, and nu and x_i are the given data.

So I tried something like:

```
nu=np.linspace(0.05,1.0,500)
x_i=model(4.5,1,2/3,nu)+np.random.normal(0,0.05,len(nu))

A=np.arange(0.0,10.0,0.1)
nu_0=np.arange(0.0,5.0,0.1)
alpha=np.arange(0.0,5.0,0.1)
sigma=0.05

AA, NU, Alpha = np.meshgrid(A,nu_0,alpha,indexing="ij")

L=log_likelihood_function(AA,NU,Alpha,nu,x_i,sigma)
```

The function should take in the values of the parameters at each point on the mesh grid but take in the entire arrays $nu$ and $x_i$ as constants at each point.

```
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) Input In [7], in <cell line: 24>()
>      20 sigma=0.05
>      22 AA, NU, Alpha = np.meshgrid(A,nu_0,alpha,indexing="ij")
> ---> 24 L=log_likelihood_function(AA,NU,Alpha,nu,x_i,sigma)
>      26 # Initialize an array to store the results
>      27 results = np.zeros_like(AA)
> 
> Input In [7], in log_likelihood_function(A, nu_0, alpha, nu, x_i,
> sigma)
>       4 nu=np.array(nu)
>       5 x_i=np.array(x_i)
> ----> 7 return -len(nu)/2*np.log(2*np.pi*sigma**2)-1/(2*sigma**2)*np.sum((x_i-A*(nu/nu_0)**alpha*(1+nu/nu_0)**(-4*alpha))**2)
> 
> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes
> (500,) (100,50,50)
```

Comment: Full error message please.  If possible identify the operator, and the shapes of the operands.

Comment: you may have to split those long `return` lines up to isolate the problem operator.

Answer (score 0):

I should wait for you to answer my comment, but my curiosity got the better of me.

Your functionn:

```
In [94]: def log_likelihood_function(A,nu_0,alpha,nu,x_i,sigma):
    ...:     nu=np.array(nu)
    ...:     x_i=np.array(x_i)
    ...: 
    ...:     return -len(nu)/2*np.log(2*np.pi*sigma**2)-1/(2*sigma**2)*np.sum((x_i-A*(nu/nu_0)**alpha*(1+nu/nu_0)**(-4*alpha))**2)
    ...: 
    ...: def model(A,nu_0,alpha,nu):
    ...: 
    ...:     return A*(nu/nu_0)**alpha*(1+nu/nu_0)**(-4*alpha)
    ...:
```

Why the

```
nu=np.array(nu)  
x_i=np.array(x_i)`
```

lines?  Aren't those arrays already?

`model` runs just fine:

```
In [95]: nu=np.linspace(0.05,1.0,500)
    ...: x_i=model(4.5,1,2/3,nu)+np.random.normal(0,0.05,len(nu))

In [96]: x_i.shape
Out[96]: (500,)

In [97]: A=np.arange(0.0,10.0,0.1)
    ...: nu_0=np.arange(0.0,5.0,0.1)
    ...: alpha=np.arange(0.0,5.0,0.1)
    ...: sigma=0.05
    ...: 
    ...: AA, NU, Alpha = np.meshgrid(A,nu_0,alpha,indexing="ij")

In [98]: AA.shape
Out[98]: (100, 50, 50)
```

and the meshgrid producing 3 3d arrays.

Here's the error:

```
In [99]: L=log_likelihood_function(AA,NU,Alpha,nu,x_i,sigma)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[99], line 1
----> 1 L=log_likelihood_function(AA,NU,Alpha,nu,x_i,sigma)

Cell In[94], line 5, in log_likelihood_function(A, nu_0, alpha, nu, x_i, sigma)
      2 nu=np.array(nu)
      3 x_i=np.array(x_i)
----> 5 return -len(nu)/2*np.log(2*np.pi*sigma**2)-1/(2*sigma**2)*np.sum((x_i-A*(nu/nu_0)**alpha*(1+nu/nu_0)**(-4*alpha))**2)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (500,) (100,50,50)
```

The error doesn't say which operator, but clearly identifies the array dimensions.

(100,50,50)  is one of meshgrid arrays.

What's the long (500,) arrays, `nu`, `xi` supposed to broadcast with?  Not any of the `meshgrid` arrays.

ipython highlights the `nu/nu_0`.

```
In [100]: nu.shape
Out[100]: (500,)

In [101]: nu_0.shape
Out[101]: (50,)
```

That's a problem, though not the immediate error:

```
In [102]: nu/nu_0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[102], line 1
----> 1 nu/nu_0

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (500,) (50,)
```

Like I commented, this long line needs to be broken up to isolate the problem operation.  And track your dimensions carefully.

### edit

```
In [105]: def log_likelihood_function(A,nu_0,alpha,nu,x_i,sigma):
     ...:     temp1 = -len(nu)/2*np.log(2*np.pi*sigma**2)
     ...:     temp2 = 1/(2*sigma**2) 
     ...:     print(nu.shape, nu_0.shape)
     ...:     nu/nu_0
     ...:     temp3 = np.sum((x_i-A*(nu/nu_0)**alpha*(1+nu/nu_0)**(-4*alpha))**2)
     ...:     return temp1 - temp2 * temp3
     ...:     

In [105]: 

In [106]: L=log_likelihood_function(AA,NU,Alpha,nu,x_i,sigma)
(500,) (100, 50, 50)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[106], line 1
----> 1 L=log_likelihood_function(AA,NU,Alpha,nu,x_i,sigma)

Cell In[105], line 5, in log_likelihood_function(A, nu_0, alpha, nu, x_i, sigma)
      3 temp2 = 1/(2*sigma**2) 
      4 print(nu.shape, nu_0.shape)
----> 5 nu/nu_0
      6 temp3 = np.sum((x_i-A*(nu/nu_0)**alpha*(1+nu/nu_0)**(-4*alpha))**2)
      7 return temp1 - temp2 * temp3

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (500,) (100,50,50)
```

OK, so `nu_0` is the 3d meshgrid array.  So the question remains, how is the (500,) supposed to play with the 3d meshgrid arrays?